# How to find out if my laravel collections match

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to find out if my old products is an exact match to my new products.
For example I have a laravel collection of 5 old products and another collection of 5 new products and
what I need to know is if the 5 old products matches the 5 new products if they do the success if not it fails,
also if the new products has more then the old products, but the old products still matches the new products then
it's a success as well

Here is my code

```
    public function changeProducts(Category $category)
    {
        $old_category = $category;
        $old_products = Product::where('category_id', $old_category->id)->get();

        $new_category = Category::find(request('category'));
        $new_products = Product::where('category_id', $new_category->id)->get();

        $diff = $old_products->diff($new_products);
        dd($diff);
    }
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question, it is not so clear

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Your approach is correct and working, you just have not gone all the way.

```
// This will return empty if all the data in old
// collection matches the new collection, even if the new
// collection has more data.
$diff = $old_products->diff($new_products);

if (count($diff) > 0) {
    echo "They do no match";   // write your code.
}
else {
    echo "They much, doesn't matter if new collection has more.";  // write your code.
}
```